# How to clip vega-lite text inside a rect?

Tags: text, truncate, clip, rect, vega-lite

In a webpage created with node/webpack, vega-lite, and `vegaEmbed`, I have a layer with `rect` marks with short annotations inside them using `text` marks.  I'd like to clip the `text` to its surrounding `rect` but haven't figured out a way to do this and hope someone can point me in the right direction.

- I realize `text` has a [`limit`](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/text.html) property in pixel units.  If I could determine the pixel units of my `rect` marks (I don't know how to do this), using limit seems like a reasonable approach.
- Also, if I knew the pixel extents of my rectangle, I can then write code to align the text within the rect which would be desirable.  Currently I just use the same `x` as the rect, with a `dx` offset.
- I've read about [background for `text`](https://github.com/vega/vega/issues/1820) which is a similar problem, but not the same.